# JS - Delete Table Row not working?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a add and delete row. I have set it up for design elements with a `div`, However when i try and delete a row it doesn't delete, i was wondering if you might be able to help.

Check it out here with the HTML code too!

http://jsfiddle.net/D77Dz/1/

```
<script language="javascript">
    function addRow(tableID) {
        var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);
        var colCount = table.rows[0].cells.length;

        for(var i=0; i<colCount; i++) {
            var newcell = row.insertCell(i);
            newcell.innerHTML = table.rows[0].cells[i].innerHTML;
            //alert(newcell.childNodes);
            switch(newcell.childNodes[0].type) {
                case "text":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].value = "";
                    break;
                case "checkbox":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].checked = false;
                    break;
                case "select-one":
                    newcell.childNodes[0].selectedIndex = 0;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    function deleteRow(tableID) {
        try {
            var table = document.getElementById(tableID);
            var rowCount = table.rows.length;

            for(var i=0; i<rowCount; i++) {
                var row = table.rows[i];
                var chkbox = row.cells[5].childNodes[0];
                if (null != chkbox && true == chkbox.checked) {
                    if(rowCount <= 1) {
                        alert("Cannot delete all the rows.");
                        break;
                    }
                    table.deleteRow(i);
                    rowCount--;
                    i--;
                }
            }
        }catch(e) {
            alert(e);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
var chkbox = row.cells[5].childNodes[0];
```

should be this:

```
var chkbox = row.cells[5].children[0].children[0];
```

---

The way you had it, you were referring to a *TextNode*.

When you change it to `.children[0]`, you get the `DIV` element that wraps the input, so you need to get the first child element of that `DIV`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line:

```
var chkbox = row.cells[5].childNodes[0];
```

to:

```
var chkbox = row.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're problem is in referring to the chkbox element, in `deleteRow`, here:

```
var chkbox = row.cells[5].childNodes[0];
```

When you have problems, try using `console.log` to trace your code at potentially hazardous lines.
In this example `console.log(chkbox)` returns the wrapping div, and not the checkbox as was intended. so change to:

```
var chkbox = row.cells[5].childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
```

or forget the whole long tree traversal by using the [queryselector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector)

```
var chkbox = row.querySelector('input[type=checkbox]');
```

see the working fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/SpacePineapple/D77Dz/2/

---

P.S I saw you were trying to implement *placeholders* (default values). You might want to take a look at the html5 specification for placeholder

- http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_placeholder.asp
- http://davidwalsh.name/html5-placeholder